# C same code, VScode compile, VisualStudio no

Tags: c

I have successfully installed and configured visual studio and vscode.
With vscode compile and run, while visual studio I have this error:
 "used local variable 'num' not initialized"
Why??

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *my_malloc( size_t n ) {
  void *p;
  p = malloc( n );
  if ( p == NULL ) {
      printf( ".....\n" );
      exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  } 

  return p;
}


char *read_n( int *num ) {
  char *a; 
  int i;
  printf("Quanti elementi: ");
  scanf( "%d", num );

  a = my_malloc( *num * sizeof(char) );
  for ( i = 0; i < *num; i++ ) {
    scanf( " %c", a + i );
  }

  return a;
}


int main() {
  int *num;

  char *array = read_n(num);

  for (int i=0; i < *num; i++) {
    printf("\n%c", array[i]);
  }


}
```

Comment: Well Visual Studio is right - you're using num without initializing it. Chances are you're using a different compiler with vscode that only treats this as a warning, and you haven't turned warnings on for the compile?

Comment: Perhaps `int num;` in main and then `char *array = read_n(&num);`? Then `for (int i=0; i < num; i++)` Additionally, you cannot use any input function correctly without validating the return... (you also killed syntax highlighting with your edit. Either indent code by 4-spaces for auto-highlight, or if you surround in 3-backticks, you must place the language name after the opening, e.g. `\`\`\`c`) Suggest using VS Developers Command Prompt and compile from command line with `cl /nologo /W3 /wd4996 /Ox /FeNameOfExe yoursource.c` The `/W3` warnings will help greatly.

Comment: @Rup ah ok, how do I turn on warning for compilation?

Comment: Add `/W3` as a compiler option (usually right-click project, properties, C/C++ settings, scroll down and select the `/W3` warning level) -- or you can add it as an additional compiler option.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to enabling warning in visual studio (recommend use of `/W3`) and declaring your `int num;` in `main()` and passing a pointer to `read_n` as, e.g.

```
char *array = read_n (&num);
```

There are a few more areas that need improvement. When `malloc` fails, `errno` is set allowing you to use `perror` to report the error, e.g.

```
void *my_malloc (size_t n)
{
    void *p = malloc (n);
    if (p == NULL) {
        perror ("my_malloc");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 

    return p;
}
```

No matter what you are coding in C, you cannot use any input function correctly if you fail to ***check the return***. For example in `read_n()`, you fail to check the return of `scanf` in both cases. You at minimum must check that the number of conversions expected -- actually took place. You can independently check if the return is `EOF`, `0` (indicating a *matching failure* or *input failure* if more than one conversion expected). You can do something similar to:

```
    fputs ("Quanti elementi: ", stdout);
    if (scanf ("%d", num) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

and

```
    for (i = 0; i < *num; i++)
        if (scanf (" %c", a + i) != 1) {
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
            break;
        }
```

Further in `read_n` `sizeof (char)` is defined as `1` and there is no need to include that as a multiplier in your allocation size, e.g.

```
    a = my_malloc (*num);
```

Other than that, the main issue of attempting pass an uninitialized pointer for `num` from `main()` can be corrected as follows:

```
int main (void) {

    int num;

    char *array = read_n (&num);

    putchar ('\n');
    for (int i=0; i < num; i++) {
        putchar (array[i]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    free (array);     /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
}
```

Lastly, as shown above, don't forget to `free` what you allocate. For allocations used in `main()` it doesn't matter as the memory will be freed on program exit. However, when your dynamic allocations are created and used several functions deep in your program that doesn't simply run and exit, failing to `free` what you allocate before the pointer goes out of scope will result in a *memory-leak*. Develop good habits early. Track your allocations and free what you allocate.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.